# Is there any prophet who is alive?

Tags: prophets

In this week's Friday prayer that I attended at a new mosque, the speaker told a story of a Prophet was praying and the angel of death came to him and told him he is there to take his spirit. The Prophet cried and the angel asked him the reason to witch he said he won't be able to pray when everyone else would be praying (His death prayer). God told the angel to not take his spirit and he would remain alive till the day of judgement (or maybe his spirit I couldn't understand clearly). My question is this really be possible because I heard from many sources that every human being has to die?

### Edit:

Doing search on Google I found out he might be talking about [Hazrat Khizr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khidr).

Comment: Verse http://legacy.quran.com/33/40 should answer your question! al-Khizr is not a Prophet.

Comment: @Medi1Saif: Thanks. What about him beling alive?

Comment: That's a claim I heard of -it's hard to believe- but Allah knows best!

Answer (score 1):

Every prophet is a human being just like me and you but were given the power to perform miracles by the will of God ( by gods permission) . God says in the Quran "Every soul shall taste death" therefore every human being including the prophets will die eventually. Now coming to your question "Is there any prophet who is alive ? " the answer is no there are no prophets who are alive currently in the world today as prophet Muhammed (pbuh) was the last and final messenger.

Comment: I have heard story about some sahaba named Qaisar n companions who are sleeping is mountains etc

Answer (score 0):

Asslamaualikum, Brother

Respectfully, you should ask the speaker what he actually meant and for a further explanation. Khizr (AS) being a prophet is debated by scholars, but it is agreed upon that he was a man blessed with ilm al ghaib from Allah (SWT).

About, the Prophets being alive. All the Prophets have passed away in this life except Isa (AS). Isa (AS) is the only prophet who is living, in the heavens as a result of being lifted by Allah (SWT). How and Why is again unseen/unknown knowledge.

[image: The only statement of the [true] believers when they are called to Allah and His Messenger to judge between them is that they say, "We hear and we obey." And those are the successful.]

Answer (score -1):

all the prophets have passed away as Mohammed (peace be upon him) was the last and final prophet. however isa (as) will be resserected to kill dajjal and after doing so will die like the rest of the humans that will witness the final hours of this dunya.

Comment: @f ahmed - Isa (Alayhisalam) will not be "resurrected" to kill dajjal. Isa (Alayhisalam) shall descend back to Earth to kill the dajjal.

Answer (score -2):

Alslam Alykom ,
My brother , All prophets are died in this life , except Essa -peace be upon him-
because he will back again to kill Antichrist , then will be died also .

You can read this Fatwa :
https://islamqa.info/en/20505